# Choose a branch cut using assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I understand [Sqrt](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html) function won't simplify expressions such as $\sqrt{x^2}$ unless there is an assumption that $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In my computation, I get an output containing an expression like this after FullSimplify:

$$e^{i\phi}-\sqrt{e^{2i\phi}}$$

I attempted to use [Assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) as mentioned as above but it still won't simplify. The exact code I used is this:

```
$Assumptions = 2*π > {ϕ} > 0 && ϕ ∈ Reals ;
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions aren't quite strict enough -- for example, if $\phi=\frac{3\pi}2$, then $e^{i\phi}=-i$, but $\sqrt{e^{2i\phi}}=i$.

(Also, you have an error in your `$Assumptions` expression; $\phi$ should not have list brackets around it.)

Try instead:

```
$Assumptions = -π/2 < ϕ ≤ π/2;
E^(I ϕ) - Sqrt[E^(2 I ϕ)] // Simplify
(* => 0 *)
```

(You don't have to explicitly state that $\phi\in\mathbb R$, because the fact that it can be compared in an inequality already implies that it's real; the field of complex numbers is not ordered.)

Comment: Yes... Thank you for pointing that out. Also just a quick thing: can I ask if there is a difference in using Simplify[] versus // Simplify?

Comment: @Histoscienology No, `Simplify[x]`, `Simplify@x` (prefix), and `x//Simplify` (postfix) are all equivalent (although they have different precedence rules). See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html) for more information.